# Mongo db service is not running

Tags: mongodb

mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-10-19 11:54:22 BST; 1min 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 28567 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 28565 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28559 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28557 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld mongod[28567]: Unrecognized option: security
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld mongod[28567]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Oct 19 11:54:22 d203.tld systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.

Comment: Check the config file, should be - bindIp: [127.0.0.1, X.X.X.X]

Comment: my service is not runing mongod.service file if i change in configuration but no effect because service not run.

Comment: can you paste your mongod.conf file? It looks like the configuration file has some unknown option which is not supported by MongoDB. In the error message it is complaining about "Unrecognized option: security"